# Exclude regex group value

Tags: c#, regex

I have next regular expression

```
\w*\|(?<PORT>\w*)\|(?<NAME>\w*)\|
```

I would like to get any match except where `PORT` equal to 220

For example:

`0|220|Camry|` - match must be excluded

`0|112|Polo|` - it is ok for match

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a negative lookahead:

```
\w*\|(?!220\|)(?<PORT>\w*)\|(?<NAME>\w*)\|
     ^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: This is not suit to what I've expected. This regex return match but with empty PORT group. I would entirely exclude match

Comment: You have an extra `(` in your regex, it should be: `\w*\|(?!220\|)(?<PORT>\w*)\|(?<NAME>\w*)\|`.

Comment: @AlexFilipovici this regex returns match but exclude prohibited value in group. I don't want to get match at all, if string has prohibited value

Comment: It only returns one match. Here's the proof: [http://regex101.com/r/lT6kM7](http://regex101.com/r/lT6kM7).